# Search for value in variable Google Apps Script/JS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Trying to determine if calendar events in Google Calendar were created by the user himself or if a CSV bulk upload was performed. If the script finds an ID with "CSV" somewhere in the value, then remove it. I tried to add an `if` statement where it looks at the variable 'res' that is using `match`, I think this is the part where I am wrong:

```
 var id_s = ev.getId(); 

    var res = id_s.match(/CSVConvert/g);

    if (res = true)  {
```

As you can see, i still get all events that do not contain 'CSVConvert'

[image]

This is what i have so far:

```
function myFunction() {

  var calendarId = 'user.name@altostrat.com';

  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId); 
  var events = calendar.getEvents(new Date('June 18, 2015 00:00:00 CST'), new Date('June 18, 2015 18:00:00 CST'));
  for(var i=0; i<events.length;i++){
    var ev = events[i];

    var id_s = ev.getId(); 

    var res = id_s.match(/CSVConvert/g);

    if (res = true)  {


      Logger.log("ID: " + ev.getId());
      Logger.log("TITLE: " + ev.getTitle());
      Logger.log("DATECREATED: " + ev.getDateCreated());
      Logger.log("LAST UPDATED: " + ev.getLastUpdated());

    }
    else{
      Logger.log("No event ID's contains: CSVConvert")
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: nicely presented question, first time I see an animation around here... very funny ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Logger a bit more would have given you the solution, or at least shown you where it failed.

Try like this :

```
Logger.log('match result = '+res);// when a match is found, res is equal to the matching string
if (res!=null)  { // otherwise it returns null
```

By the way, the `equal` condition is a `==` (double equal), in this case I used not equal (`!=`)